# Multivariable polynomial in $R[X_1,..,X_n]$ whose roots are all elements in $R^n$ is zero.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Suppose that the roots of $p\in R[x_1,...,x_n]$, where R is algebraically closed and $n\geq 1 $, is the entire set $R^n$, is $p$ necessarily the zero polynomial. I think it might be true but I cant prove it. I know that it holds for the case n=1 since polynomials of degree $k$ can have at most k roots. But it is possible for multivariable polynomials to have infinite roots and still not be zero.

So I would like to know if p is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. Yes, $p$ is zero and what we need to use is that $R$ is infinite (which is implied since it is algebraically closed in your case).

The idea is to induct (because we understand polynomials in one variable after all!). The result is folklore for $n = 1$. Let $$0 \neq p \in R[x_1, \dots, x_n] = R[x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}][x_n].$$ Since $p \neq 0$, there exists some $f \in R[x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}]$ such that $0 \neq p(f) \in R[x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}]$. By induction hypothesis, there exists $a_1, \dots, a_{n-1} \in R$ such that $p(f)(a_1, \dots, a_{n-1}) \neq 0$. In particular, $p(a_1, \dots, a_{n-1}, f(a_1, \dots, a_{n-1})) \neq 0$.

Comment: Hi, why should such an a exist thanks.

Comment: Ah yes, that was a typo, I fixed it. For your second question, you said you know the result for $n = 1$, i.e. $f \in S[x]$ with $S$ infinite ring, then there exists $a \in S$ with $f(a) \neq 0$. Apply this with $S = R[x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}]$.

Comment: Yes but doesnt that mean a should be in $R[x_1,...,x_{n-1}]$ and not necessarily in R.

Comment: Hm, you are right. However, the proof still works since you will plug in an element of $R$ eventually after $n$ steps in the induction. Let me fix my answer.